# How to start list of names from name "image100" and set limit 100 next names?

Tags: php

I have a script:

```
foreach(glob('/res/images/*.jpg') as $filename)
{
   $filename = basename($filename, ".jpg");
   $items = "$filename<br>";
}
return $items;
```

output is a file names:
`image1`
`image2`
...
`image16354327`

**Question**:
How to start list of names from name `image100` and set limit 100 next names?

Comment: By using a `for` loop with `array_count` as the limit

Comment: Thanks for answer, but can you post code here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of results for glob directory/folder listing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471935/limit-number-of-results-for-glob-directory-folder-listing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/image100*.jpg'), 0, 100) as $filename)
{
    $filename = basename($filename, ".jpg");
    $items = "$filename<br>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but I think he wants image100.jpg, image101.jpg, image102.jpg and so on.

Comment: `glob('/res/images/image10*.jpg')` I think you need to it ;)

Comment: Hm, `foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/image100*.jpg'), 0, 999) as $filename)` is work fine but `foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/image100*.jpg'), 0, 1000) as $filename)` doesnt work. Where is I can change such limit?

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying your pattern like this:
`glob('/res/images/image1{0..9}{0..9}.jpg')`

I've never actually used brace expansion with glob but this should get you `image100.jpg`, `image101.jpg`, `image102.jpg`, on up to `image199.jpg`. Is that what you're looking for?